# Some change events work, while others dont

Tags: excel, vba

The first two Subs work, and the last one doesn't.

I insert values in the "ProsrochkaTextBox" but "ProsrochkaResult" return any value.

I have checked Change Event Enable option and it works perfectly fine

Also, changing the sequence of code doesn't help

```
Private Sub K1TextBox_Change()
  If K1TextBox < 0.13 Then
    K1Result = 0
  ElseIf K1TextBox < 0.2 Then
    K1Result = 0.5
  ElseIf K1TextBox < 0.36 Then
    K1Result = 1
  ElseIf K1TextBox < 0.65 Then
    K1Result = 1.5
  Else
    K1Result = 2
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub K4TextBox_Change()
  If K4TextBox < 0.3 Then
    K4Result = 0
  ElseIf K4TextBox < 1.2 Then
    K4Result = 0.5
  ElseIf K4TextBox < 1.5 Then
    K4Result = 1
  ElseIf K4TextBox < 2.5 Then
    K4Result = 1.5
  Else
    K4Result = 2
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub ProsrochkaResult_Change()
  If ProsrochkaTextBox < 0.025 Then
    ProsrochkaResult = 2
  ElseIf ProsrochkaTextBox < 0.1 Then
    ProsrochkaResult = 1.5
  ElseIf ProsrochkaTextBox < 0.2 Then
    ProsrochkaResult = 1
  ElseIf ProsrochkaTextBox < 0.3 Then
    ProsrochkaResult = 0.5
  Else
    ProsrochkaResult = 0
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" does not really explain the problem. When you put a break point (F9) on the first line of the one that "doesn't work", what happens? You can step thru it line by line using F8.

Comment: Your change event routine is for a Control named `ProsrochkaResult` but within the routine you use `ProsrochkaTextBox` - is this on purpose? Have you set a breakpoint to the routine? Are you using `Option Explicit`?